yarn install in gitlab ci runner creates error "The lockfile would have been modified by this install, which is explicitly forbidden."
I am working on
react-native 0.75.2
yarn 3.6.4
node 20

In my project, I have a native module dependency, which is located inside my project folder. My package.json looks like
"dependencies": { 
  ....,
  "react-native-my-native-mod": "file:native_modules/react-native-my-native-mod", 
}

In gitlab-runner, it is creating an error because in gitlab-ci.yml, I have script like
yarn install --immutable

The error is "The lockfile would have been modified by this install, which is explicitly forbidden."
and it shows checksum difference in my native module.
I am using .yarnrc.yml that looks like
nodeLinker: node-modules
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.4.cjs

I guess, when the project is locally installed by yarn install, the module is installed from the location I have specified in package.json i.e. file:native_modules/react-native-my-native-mod
But gitlab-runner is trying to install the module from builds folder i.e.
file:builds/0/project-0/native_modules/react-native-my-native-mod

As a result, the checksum is changed and it creates the above-mentioned error.
Or maybe some other reason behind it.
How to solve this?

Ideally, you'd figure out why yarn ends up with a different package checksum in the CI environment, and then fix the cause so yarn.lock isn't modified in the first place. That might be difficult, though  (other people are reporting similar issues with no solution so far, e.g. here).
As a workaround, you could explicitly update the checksum/hash for your (well-known/trusted) local package before running yarn install --immutable, e.g. like this:
yarn up react-native-my-native-mod@file:native_modules/react-native-my-native-mod

After that, your install shouldn't fail anymore under normal circumstances, but will still fail if any other checksum mismatch occurs.

Thanks for the suggestion, It worked like magic and saved my day :)

The directory builds/0/project-0/ is the clone of the remote repository and the content of builds/0/project-0/native_modules/react-native-my-native-mod is the same as native_modules/react-native-my-native-mod in the repo.
To fix it, clone the repo, and run
yarn cache clean --all
yarn install

and push the updated yarn.lock to the repository. This will fix the issue.

Thanks for the suggestion. I have already tried this. But no luck.
